# Adding returned tuples to a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to add the returned tuples to a list of lists or list of arrays.

```
    dim = 10
    for key, figure in sorted(problem.figures.iteritems(), reverse=True):
        dim -= 1
        # print key, dim 
        (img_arr[dim], images[dim]) = vectorize(figure)
```

The function returns an array and an image. I am trying to create a list of arrays and a list of images. Can I do this without initializing a list of images outside of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
img_arr[dim], images[dim] = vectorize(figure)
```

Comment: This gave me an error,
"NameError: global name 'images' is not defined"
I had img_arr defined and used earlier and so, not surprising that I did not get an error for that

Answer (score 0):

Try using `append()` attribute of list like this:

```
img_arr, images = [],[] # assuming you already declared the list

for key, figure in sorted(problem.figures.iteritems(), reverse=True):
     tup = vectorize(figure)
     img_arr.append(tup[0])
     images.append(tup[1])
```

> The method append() appends a passed obj into the existing list.